# How to structure database for good crud functionality and optimal response time

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures

I have a schema for designing a warehouse management system and so far is went well till this point. My database has several tables but the most important of them all is the Invoices table. My issue is when a customer comes to buy, he may buy one or more items and I thought I could just make every entry with regard to the same customer into the invoices table and just make the unique identifier OR a special code for identifying each unique customer AND THE ITEMS LINKED TO HIM OR HER but I am now wondering if there might be a better way to do so such that if possible I could generate function to create spaces for every potential customer with space for a number of items which may be purchased and. I am thinking an array List could help but I don't have enough knowledge on how to implement such a function to create unique lists of items bought per each customer and display it to a J table. Any ideas or references are very welcome.

This is the table:

```
TABLE INVOICES      

 Id,
 ItemDescription,
Invoice Number,
 Quantity,
 Transaction Type,
 Balance,
 Discount,
 Invoice Date,
 Amount Payed,
 Invoice Sum,
 Overall Total.


TABLE CUSTOMERS
     Id 
First Name,
 Last Name,
  Contact,
   Email,
 Location
```

I am using java with MySQL and net beans IDE 8.0.2

Comment: Have you heard of using punctuation?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I am not sure I understand your question entirely.

The common way to model this is:

```
Customer
------------
customer_id
....

Product
--------
product_id
....

Purchase_header
--------
purchase_id
customer_id
......

purchase_line
--------------
purchase_id
product_id
quantity
price_each
total_price
......

invoice
-------
invoice_id
purchase_id
amount
....

payment
-------
payment_id
invoice_id
amount
......
```

In other words...
A customer has 0..n purchases

A purchase has 1..n line items, for 1 product, with a quantity, price per item, and total price

A purchase has 0..n invoices (think of refunds as a negative invoice)

An invoice has 0..n payments

Comment: very helpful...indeed .i've decided to use 2 tables ..one to display data in this  fromat below

Comment: ||Table Invoice Sheet||    Customer_ID, Invoice_ID,Transaction_Type,Balance,Discount,Invoice date,Amount Paid,Reversals,Sum and Overall Total.... then id use a second Table to display the items bound to a specific Customer_ID and Invoice_ID   as follows               ....|| Table Invoices_has_stock_items||  ---->  Customer_ID,Invoice_ID,Item_Code,Quantity,Total